# Why is the site in "read-only mode"?

Tags: discussion, maintenance, read-only

I just saw this:

> This site is currently in read-only mode; we’ll return with full functionality soon.

What happened? Was there some sort of hacking incident?

Comment: Probably maintenance or new patch deployed

Comment: Clever attackers destroyed the entire site and replaced it with an exact duplicate. Those bastards.

Comment: Who cares? Seriously. Does there need to be a Meta question for every 10-second outage now? If it's something major, it's going to be on https://www.stackstatus.net/

Comment: The site goes to a read-only mode whenever Jon Skeet logs out, so he won't be under threat from any other users. But that usually only lasts a couple of minutes. Most likely this was his weekly nap time.

Comment: That's a hellban put on users after we take a vote on whether or not we like them.  Sorry, voted for you, but these other guys, pfft.

Comment: With such a good answer, I don't see how this question was considered so useless: 17 downvotes so far! Except people here are too harsh on questions sometimes.

Comment: @Cawas Meh, whatever. The downvotes don't really bother me- I have a pretty thick skin :P Thanks for looking out for me, though!

Comment: **RELATED:** [Read-only mode status message, Request to add links to official status pages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231126/read-only-mode-status-message-request-to-add-links-to-official-status-pages)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**EDIT**: This answer only applies to the read only/downtime event in November 2013. For up to date Stack Exchange status, check [@StackStatus on Twitter](http://twitter.com/StackStatus) and/or [stackstatus.net](https://www.stackstatus.net/)

---

From [@stackstatus on Twitter](http://twitter.com/stackstatus):

> We are failing over to our secondary SQL setup, there may be a slight interruption. #stackoverflow #stackexchange

Its probably related to that

And scrolling a little further down the Twitter timeline I ran into this from Nick Craver:

> Typically we have thousands of plans in cache, but after a routing job, it’s as if caching has been disabled #sqlhelp

Answer (score 1):

The best place to check for a current answer to this question seems to be to check [@stackstatus on Twitter](http://twitter.com/stackstatus).

Comment: See [the accepted answer from 5.5 months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/208794/246931)...

Comment: @Nick Stauner Should I then delete the specific instance information from the old accepted answer?  I used the above answer gratefully to find out why it was happening again.  : )

Comment: I suppose you could [suggest an edit to it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/208794/edit) that makes it clearer that you can check the page for updates at any time, but no guarantees it'd be accepted of course. Since your answer doesn't add anything unique beyond that, I fear you might be courting downvotes ;) (Not that I'm encouraging anyone to do so with this comment...seems a little pointless.)

Comment: @Nick is correct, twitter is already mentioned and linked to from the other answer, maybe comment there or edit might fit but not new answer just to tell "twitter is the place to check".

Comment: I've updated my answer to point out that the answer only applies to the event that happened in November 2013.