# Add links to official status pages in the read-only mode status message

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange, read-only

When the site is in read-only mode, I get a message like this:

> This site is currently in read-only mode.

Would it be possible to update that message to provide links to these resources on SE's status:

- [**twitter.com/StackStatus**](https://twitter.com/StackStatus): Official SE tweets on SE's status.
- [**stackstatus.net**](https://www.stackstatus.net/): Official blog posts on SE's status.

Comment: Seems sensible to me. I might even go so far as to say "Show the last tweet from @StackStatus" so if something's really broken we can see the most recent update.

Comment: @voretaq7: Embedding the last tweet within the alert would take time to code; editing the alert message (assuming they're not hard-coded in 100+ places) would not take as nearly as much time, and would not be "new" functionality, just text editing.

Comment: I'm not saying it's zero effort, I'm saying it would be *useful* and should be done if feasible. Nearly every SE chat I'm in right now has *multiple* links to the stack status tweet explaining the recent test because people keep asking - this would obviate that need. (Besides, I'm a user here: I reserve the right to put on blinders and not care how much development effort a feature request may take - it's all written by unicorns anyway! :-)

Comment: @voretaq7: And what if Twitter is broken as well? :-P

Comment: @AmalMurali "Then you have bigger problems" :-)