# iOS app crashes silently when sites are offline

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, read-only

I have the latest iOS app from the store on my iPhone 5 w/ iOS 7.1.1 device.  When I launched it this morning when pretty much [all of SE was offline](https://twitter.com/StackStatus/status/467197790460706816), it crashed silently.  [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231167/provide-an-indicator-that-site-is-in-read-only-mode) seems to indicate that that app works in read-only mode, but that didn't happen for me.  When the sites came back online, the app behaved as normal.

If it matters, I was already logged in via Google, and I am pretty sure I had pending notifications in my inbox (I think this is why I open the app).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this!

I have found the crash report that describes your issue. It looks like one of your caches was turning up empty, causing an array out of bounds exception. I have fixed this, but the fix will be deployed in the Appstore on **version 1.0.2 (or later).**