# Notice in app when site is down

Tags: feature-request, android-app, read-only

When the site went down ~10 minutes ago and I tried to load the Android app,  instead of giving me a "The site is down" message like the full site does, it just took longer to load, then showed me a restricted version of the main feed, and didn't have the profile option in the hamburger menu.

Since my phone's old, and I had a bad connection, I tried toggling my radios and restarting the app a few times before I finally thought to check the full site.

It would be nice if when you try to open the app while the site is down, it gave you a little red banner across the top with a message just so it's clear what the problem is.

Comment: [Same request for iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231167/provide-an-indicator-that-site-is-in-read-only-mode).

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's worded similarly to mine too. Still a good idea.