# What caused the 16/5/2014 downtime?

Tags: support, downtime, read-only

Today, the entire stack exchange network was in read-only mode for several hours right in the middle of normal office hours for EU. This was pretty annoying, because it meant that I couldn't ask for advice on certain subjects.

Was this just regular maintenance? if so, I can't remember it being announced in advance.

Comment: read this - https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/85902805739/stack-exchange-primary-data-center-offline-may-16th

Comment: Re downvotes; I note that the stackstatus [isn't linked to from the site when in downtime](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231126/read-only-mode-status-message-request-to-add-links-to-official-status-pages) so its not unreasonable to be curious

Comment: What @RichardTingle said. This is a perfectly legitimate support question, and the answer is only obvious if you already know it.

Comment: Right, but a [simple search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=stackoverflow+is+down) would have given information about the StackStatus Twitter link. So this question shows "no research effort".

Comment: Someone done an UPSie at the hosting provider. https://twitter.com/nick_craver/status/467240946372202496

Comment: I think that stackstatus.net should be linked in the "the page is read only" text, explaining that more information might appear there later.

Comment: Also note that Stackexchange websites are owned and hosted in the US and this issue came in the middle of the night there. They acted quickly IMHO.

Comment: As people correctly deduced, I was unaware of the existence of the stackstatus.net website. If I knew about this website, I wouldn't have asked this question. I agree that it should be publicized more clearly when this happens again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Stack Exchange Primary Data Center Offline - May 16th, 2014](https://stackstatus.tumblr.com/post/85902805739/stack-exchange-primary-data-center-offline-may-16th):

> Our data center racks in New York unexpectedly lost connectivity. There was a failure in the UPS feeding our equipment that went undetected by our provider. Here is a timeline of major events so far:
>
> - 06:43 UTC - The UPS feeding our racks in the New York data center stopped feeding utility power and failed to provider backup power
> - 07:04 UTC - We learned the nature of the UPS issue and began failover to our Oregon facility
> - 07:07 UTC - Oregon came online in read-only mode
> - 07:10-09:00 UTC - We experienced issues with stability in Oregon due to the expected failover with caching and database connections. We will detail these issues in the postmortem.
> - 09:50 UTC - New York data center regains power
> - 09:54 UTC - Load balancers were reactivated and New York is again reachable.
> - 09:56 UTC - SQL Databases are online and restoring databases
> - 10:00 UTC - SQL Databases came back online without any apparent damage (phew)

Comment: Sounds like a hectic morning for the SE Staff.

Comment: @Amicable for some staff members, it was the middle of the night.

Comment: 06:43 UTC is like 01:43 in New York.