# Bounties should not be active during readonly mode

Tags: feature-request, bounties, read-only

When a Stack Exchange site stays in readonly mode, bounties are active, despite the fact that the questions can not receive any response. I think the bounties should be made inactive during readonly mode - they should be stopped and shouldn't expire.

Comment: What do you mean "inactive bounty"? Don't show that there is a bounty when viewing a question?

Comment: @Sha It can be shown but it shouldn't last. Time should stop.

Comment: Hours maybe, but days? No.

Comment: I agree with the *idea*, but only if the read-only period was hours, perhaps anything more than 6 hours. Then the site extends all bounties active within the read-only period by X hours rounded down to the nearest hour. But then the idea is pointless, really, as I don't think there has ever been a read-only period for more than minutes. Certainly not an amount of *hours* which would arguably be a significant loss to bounty being answerable. The chance of outages are also more unlikely as time goes on too, as Datacentres have more intelligent and reliable rollover and redundancy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bounty is paying for advertising the question, not a guaranteed answer. During a read only event, you're still advertising your question.

And most read only events only last a few minutes. One exception to this was the recent [UPS outage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231736/what-caused-the-16-5-2014-downtime/231737) where Stack Exchange was either down or in read only for three hours. But even then, sites enter and exit read only without much fanfare.

In the end, the purpose of the bounty still happens in read only mode. And I'm not sure it's really worth the development effort because the admin's have poured a lot of effort to keep the sites online.

Comment: Point taken. ))

Comment: And those 3 hours when we could not interact with **any** [se] site were *perfect* to research and craft nice answers to bounty questions!